# $f:[\pi,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R^2}$, $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[\pi,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R^2}$ which is defined as

> $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$

Now i want to know can we draw the diagram of this question,as we can see that for a circle the coordinates are $(r\cos x,r\sin x)$ here the radius is $1$ and the interval is $2nd$ and third quadrant.So the diagram is half part of circle.
Is i am right?

Please clear my doubt.

Comment: Third and fourth quadrant.  The first two go from $0$ to $\pi$.  Looks fine otherwise.  Cheers!

Comment: one more question sir ,the function is continious and differentiable ,why can't i apply cauchy's  mean  value theorem.

Comment: Apply it to what?  But yes, you should be able to use it.

Comment: this is a mutilple choice question ,and here is a option that "There does't exist $t_0 \in [\pi,2\pi] $ such that $f'(t_0)=\frac{f(2\pi)-f(\pi)}{\pi}$ why is so.

Comment: Take a close look at the mean value theorem. Which functions does it apply to? Does it say you can use it on a function like $f$?

Comment: @Arthur this applicable to all function which are continous on closed interval and differntiable on open.

Comment: does i am missing something.?

Comment: ok the range should be $\mathbb{R}$ am i right ?

Comment: Yup. That's the one. So the theorem doesn't apply. That's not to say the conclusion of the theorem isn't true, though. There might still be some $t_0$. It's just not guaranteed to exist by the theorem. So you actually have to check whether there is one or not.

Comment: Should we try to make this  theorem for multidimensional ?lol

Comment: I assume $t=x$?

Comment: yes, i will make it correct, thanx.

Comment: @Arthur: Even when the mean value theorem is formulated for real value functions, it could by chance be true in the situation here. To show that it is not you have to calculate $f(2\pi)-f(\pi)$ which equals $(2,0)$. Since $f'(t_0)=(-\sin(t_0),\cos(t_0))$ the validity of the mean value theorem would imply $t_0=3\pi/2$ when applied to the second component. But then the desired relation for the first component becomes Taler.